# Can I change my address in AdSense so the pin is mailed to my home country?

Tags: google-adsense, payments, international

I'm currently living in Ireland and I gave this address to AdSense. I had crossed the revenue threshold and they have mailed me the pin last week. But, now only I came to know that,since I'm on spouse visa, j can't work or engage in any business and also unable to get  bank account too. In this situation,

1. Can I change my address and country to my native address (India)?
2. Can I cancel this AdSense account and create new one?
3. If I do so, will I get the payment already there in the AdSense account now?

Comment: did you solve the issue ? i have situation i live in different county but going to move to india in coming year, i am about to select adsense county, which county should i select for my youtube google adsense account ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link to [Google Adsense's official documentation](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2628816?hl=en) on how to change address and country (they send you to a form you need to fill).

However, any remaining balance will be paid out through your old country profile.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to change the country of your payment address in AdSense. If you've moved to a new country or territory, you'll need to cancel your existing AdSense account and create a new AdSense account.

Comment: A quick search of AdSense help revealed this answer to be wrong.

Comment: Quick search reveals a lot of incompetence and people who cannot properly read.